# Any way to make WPF Adorner ignore mouse?

Tags: wpf, adorner

Is there any way to make WPF adorner ignore mouse entirely so that the UIElement behind the adorner still gets mouse events as if the adorner does not exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the `Adorner` to false

Answer (score 1):

If you use the *tunneling* version of the mouse events rather than the bubbling events (i.e., `PreviewMouseDown` instead of `MouseDown`), you will receive the mouse events from the `UIElement` first, and be able to stop them from reaching the adorner by setting `e.Handled` to true.